# AutoHotKeys Not sending Newline or tab from a File

Tags: special-characters, autohotkey

I want to copy a text file to a game, through the use of AHK, as Copy and Paste don't work on it.
I went on the website and found I can use this:

```
!a::
    Loop, read, D:\MoeTM\Desktop\Farm Turtle.txt
    {
        Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine
        {
            Send %A_LoopField%
            sleep 100
        }
    }
```

This makes AHK loop through the file and send all the normal characters, abc...123... But it doesn't send tabs or newlines. How would I fix this? To send tabs and newlines(I only need these special characters).

Comment: How do you know id didn't send newlines, the game could ignore them, i suggest you test sending your text to a text editor.  `n is newline

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before by Dexter, `'n` is new line and `'r` is carriage return, but could it be that you just need an <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line?
B.t.w. I used <kbd>'</kbd> in this reply, but is should be the AHK #Escape character, which is the back-tick or console key just below the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on a US layout keyboard. I used the correct character in the actual code.

When you want to end with `NewLine` and/or `CarriageReturn`

```
Send %A_LoopField%`n`r
```

or when you want to end with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Send %A_LoopField%{Enter}
```

or when you want to end with <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
Send %A_LoopField%{Tab}
```

Depending on the receiving application, just the `'n` or `'r` alone could be enough, or you might need both `'n'r` or in the reverse order `'r'n`.

Comment: Data can be stored as  `'r`, `'n`, or `'r'n`, but the enter key always sends `'r`.  `%A_LoopField%` never contains and/or ends with either line break, because AutoHotkey filters them out.  So sending {Enter} after it is safe, except for determining new lines at the end of the file, which are removed.  For the tabs, use [StringReplace](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm) to swap `'t` for `{Tab}`, before the send command.